# How do I implement a cancellable editable field in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my model, I have a field that I need several controls to bind to. One of these controls is a text box. The text box should not directly edit the field, but instead it should allow the user to type and then either commit the changes or cancel. If any other operation occurs then it should overwrite any changes in the text field. One constraint is that there are other UI components that change the value and do not have access to the local scope.

I implemented the desired behavior with a directive: http://jsfiddle.net/fLxjjmb7/3/

It works as intended, but I feel that there must be a better way to do this. Any ideas?

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
    <div>{{foo}}</div>
    <button ng-click="increment()">increment</button>
    <button ng-click="decrement()">decrement</button>
    <br />
    <div shadow="foo">
        <input type="text" ng-model="foo" />
        <button ng-click="commit()">update</button>
        <button ng-click="cancel()">cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

var controller = app.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.foo = 1;
    $scope.increment = function () { ++$scope.foo; };
    $scope.decrement = function () { --$scope.foo; };
});

var directive = app.directive('shadow', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, el, att) {
        scope.$parent.$watch(att.shadow, function (newValue) {
            scope[att.shadow] = newValue;
        });

      scope.commit = function() {
        scope.$parent[att.shadow] = angular.copy(scope[att.shadow]);
      };

      scope.cancel = function() {
          scope[att.shadow] = angular.copy(scope.$parent[att.shadow]);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you are complicating this a bit :)

View:

```
<div ng-controller="ShadowController">
    <h1>{{foo}}</h1>

    <div>
        <button ng-click="increment()">increment</button>
        <button ng-click="decrement()">decrement</button>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="tempFoo" />
        <button ng-click="commit()">update</button>
        <button ng-click="cancel()">cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('ShadowController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.foo = 1;

    $scope.increment = function () {
        ++$scope.foo;
        $scope.cancel();
    };

    $scope.decrement = function () {
        --$scope.foo;
        $scope.cancel();
    };

    $scope.commit = function () {
        $scope.foo = parseFloat($scope.tempFoo);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $scope.tempFoo = $scope.foo;
    };

    $scope.cancel();
});
```

An even fancier way would be to keep track of changes to the temporary value and only enable commit/cancel buttons if there is a diff between original and temp.

View:

```
<div ng-controller="ShadowControllerAdv">
    <h1>{{data.original}}</h1>

    <div>
        <button ng-click="increment()">increment</button>
        <button ng-click="decrement()">decrement</button>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.edit" />
        <button ng-click="commit()" ng-disabled="!state.hasChanged">update</button>
        <button ng-click="reset()" ng-disabled="!state.hasChanged">cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('ShadowControllerAdv', function ($scope) {
    var _dataWatcher;

    $scope.data = {
        original: 1
    };

    $scope.state = {
        hasChanged: false
    };

    function _startWatcher() {
        _dataWatcher = $scope.$watch('data.edit', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                $scope.state.hasChanged = true;
            } else {
                $scope.state.hasChanged = false;
            }
        }, true);
    }

    function _stopWatcher() {
        if (!_dataWatcher) {
            return;
        }
        _dataWatcher();
    }

    $scope.reset = function () {
        _stopWatcher();
        $scope.data.edit = $scope.data.original;
        $scope.state.hasChanged = false;
        _startWatcher();
    }

    $scope.commit = function () {
        _stopWatcher();
        $scope.data.original = parseFloat($scope.data.edit);
        $scope.reset();
    }

    $scope.increment = function () {
        $scope.data.original = $scope.data.original + 1;
        $scope.reset();
    };

    $scope.decrement = function () {
        $scope.data.original = $scope.data.original - 1;
        $scope.reset();
    };

    $scope.reset();
});
```

Comment: Good idea. I should have mentioned that other UI components can also change the value. They don't have access to cancel or other local scope functions.

Comment: Ok, if components outside of the controller can change the value you might wanna put the get/set logic in a factory. If the data object is stored in the factory, the "get" method returns the full data object and the "set" changes data.original - you should be golden. Might wanna add another listener in the controller though to keep track of changes made to original from the outside, call $scope.reset() if that happens.